# Why does my php HOME environment variable not match the HOME variable in my linux bash shell?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

If I echo out HOME in the command line I get

```
/root
```

If I echo out

```
getenv('HOME')
```

in php I get

```
/var/www
```

This messes up my AWS (amazon web services) scripts because I have a configuration file placed in my /root home directory which contains my credentials. I can can try a different way of loading my credentials but I want to know why this is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q: Why does my php $HOME environment variable not match my bash shell $HOME?

A: Because your web server is running in a different user context than the one you log in as.

For example:

```
 ps -eaf|grep http
root       856     1  0 Mar24 ?        00:04:10 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    4960   856  0 Aug02 ?        00:00:02 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    4961   856  0 Aug02 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    7411   856  0 Aug03 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    7413   856  0 Aug03 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    7416   856  0 Aug03 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    7420   856  0 Aug03 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
<= In this case, the web server is run as daemon user "apache"
```

PS:

> If I echo out HOME in the command line I get `/root`

This is Bad.  You should generally *always* log in as a normal user, and "sudo" those few "privileged" commands you need to run.

Avoiding the "root" login is very good habit to get into ... especially if you ever start administering a site professionally.

Answer (score 2):

You and your webserver are running as different users. Try doing `echo shell_exec("whoami");` (or the actual path to executable) and you'll see it will print something like `www-data`. This is standard procedure - even if your code is compromised, the user that the webserver is running as does not have permission to read any other data.

This is especially important since you're logged in as root. If the webserver was running under the root user, the smallest vulnerability can wreck havoc.

Comment: Recommended: `su user` where the user is the server, typically `www-data` on ubuntu in AWS. This way, you can only perform the actions of the user associated with the web-server, and you won't run into these complications when using root. Sidenote, never use root.